# Can't find much info on Tsem Rinpoche, was he a genuine lama?

Tags: mahayana, tibetan-buddhism, teachers

Does anyone know anything about Tsem Rinpoche?

I watched a few of his talks on Youtube recently, and found him to be incredibly charismatic.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than answer your question directly, you might find it helpful to think about these questions instead: How do you know if *anyone* is a genuine lama or not? How do you know Dalai Lama is genuine? How do you know Khenchen Lama is genuine?

You might also want to ask; why is it important for you that the lama is genuine? How would that affect your relationship with the lama and the teaching?

If I tell you so-and-so is genuine, you can go to the internet and find another person who will say that no, he isn't genuine. If I tell you he isn't genuine, you can also find another person who will say that yes, he is genuine. What determines whether you trust a person or not?

Hope this is helpful

Comment: It was, thanks.  I could have put in a little more thought & reflection before asking my question (makes me cringe tbh)

Comment: I'm thinking it might be helpful to follow the Buddhas advice (or plain old common sense):  just try out the teachings if they are clear and make sense, and see if they work.

Comment: While great and obvious advice, I would actually point out and refute what you said, simply by the fact that a lama is just a title, an honorific or educational title. So the simple fact is to see if this person is a genuine lama, you would need to see his geshe degree, then his references for X amount of years as a teacher (title of rinpoche) and his status as the highest teacher or abbot of a specific sect or monastery....simply that!

Answer (score 1):

Please read "[An abridged biography of H.E. the 25th Tsem Rinpoche](https://www.tsemtulku.com/biography/)". Apparently, he also published an autobiography book entitled "[The Promise: A Tsem Rinpoche Biography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9675365064)".

On this page entitled "[I’m Requesting Ordination in 1987](https://www.tsemrinpoche.com/tsem-tulku-rinpoche/me/requesting-ordination-in-1987.html)", you can find info and [a Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=161C4xrnIf0) on Tsem Rinpoche's meeting the 14th Dalai Lama and he is given assurance that he will be ordained a monk by the Dalai Lama, if he goes to India.

Tsem Rinpoche wrote:

> Then in December 1987, myself and two other boys
> had the fortune to spend three hours with His Holiness and senior
> sangha like His Eminence Denma Locho Rinpoche. That is when I received
> my ordination vows. His Holiness gave me my vows, cut my hair and
> touched my robes to bless it.
>
> Can you imagine, His Holiness did this for me!! I was so happy, I had
> finally become a monk after years of wanting to be one, starting from
> a very young age. Now, I was 22 and had just became ordained!!! It was
> a lifetime’s dream come true to be a monk and His Holiness, the
> highest of the high, ordained me himself!!! I was given the ordination
> name ‘Tenzin Zopa‘ by His Holiness.